# Remove tags and elements in it with preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this HTML line when I view my localhost page

```
<a class="moz-txt-link-abbrevi=ated" href="http://www.test.com">Test</a>
```

I want to remove the

`<a class="moz-txt-link-abbrevi=ated" href=3D"http://www.test.com">`

So pretty much preg replace everything between the `<a` and `>` to nothing since I'll get out the `</a>` at the end with string replace, and I cannot string replace the class since the href in it is always different.

I've tried this

`$outputstr = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>.*?<\/a>/', '', $outputstr);`

But then, of course, my whole line disappears because it's removing everything between `<a` to `</a>` and all I need is the content without the class tags.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

I've tried using

`$outputstr = str_replace('</a>','',$outputstr);` to take out my last `</a>`

And then

`$outputstr = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*.*?\/>/', '', $outputstr);`

in the hope to remove the

`<a class=3D"moz-txt-link-abbrevi=ated" href=3D"http://www.test.com">`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Target html isn't valid

Comment: Regex aren't suited for that. Take a look at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) it will greatly help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why not just use strip_tags?

Answer (score 3):

You were almost correct with your original attempt. The only thing you need to do now is: create a capturing group for the content and then use a backreference to that group as the replacement:

```
$outputstr = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/', '$1', $outputstr);
```

Notice the round brackets around the content. This creates a capturing group. In the replacement you refer to to this capturing group as `$1`.

Comment: This will only work if the input contains only the sole `a` element. If you throw entire html at it, it will capture everything from the first `a` element to last `a` element in the html including everything in between. Using regexes to handle html/xml is generaly not the recommended solution. Better way is to parse it with xml/html parser and then manipulate the resulting DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3 things,

**1. explode**

Since you want to remove the part till ">" and to keep the rest, you can explode and get the second element in the array. However I dont know why do you want to keep "" at the end.

```
$str = '<a class=3D"moz-txt-link-abbrevi=ated" href=3D"http://www.skyberate.nl">www.skyberate.nl</a>';

$arr = explode('>', $str);

echo $arr[1];
```

**2. strip html tags**

Use easy peasy strip tags. And this will remove the "" part. I expect you want to drop that part too.

```
$str = '<a class=3D"moz-txt-link-abbrevi=ated" href=3D"http://www.skyberate.nl">www.skyberate.nl</a>';

echo strip_tags($str);
```

**3. regular expression**

I dont recommend this as it will be slower and much more complex looking.

Cheers.

Comment: I am sorry, my issue wasn't fully explained here, I've just tried to make it as short as possible since maybe nobody likes to read much, but I've left some details out of it as well, explode is a great idea, but won't work for my usage, strip_tags works great as well but not for my usage, I still appreciate your help so I will mark this as solved, thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the last half tag, you can do it like this, [Doc: replacement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and check the live [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb95ea294b2194dfecc6721d4229965c02383a15)

```
preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>(.*?</\1>)@si', '\2', $input);
```